# Multivariate Linear Regression with continuous and discrete explanatory variable

Tags: regression, linear-model, continuous-data, multivariate-regression

I have some trouble to apply a multivariate linear regression on my data. I have two features gross_area which is continuous, nb_bathrooms which is discrete (1,2,3) and a dependent variable y which is the price. Firstly I have looked at the feature's distribution which is not normal (Skewed right). I removed some outliers. I standardized my features.I use OLS as cost function and "batch" gradient descent in order to find my parameters.
I find my parameter I plot separately the gross_area against the price with parameter gross_area and the y-intercept, and a plot of the nb_bathrooms against the price with parameter nb_bathrooms and the y-intercept also.

This is what I got for the gross_area:
[image: gross_area]
And for the nb_bedrooms:
[image]

So my questions are the following,
How can I fit data like nb_bedrooms since I tried polynomial terms but does not seem to fit them better.

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that you are predicting negative prices for small gross areas. Does that make sense (Please come and live in this appartment, I will give you money if you do). I would consider using a log link function.

As for the categorical variable, I would just add indicator variables for the number of bathrooms instead of entering it as a continuous variable.

Comment: Thank you, for you answer, effectively it does not make any sense. I should apply log link function on my predicted price matrix ?

Comment: I prefer to use a link function instead of transforming the dependent variable. That way you continue to model the mean price instead of the mean log(price).

Comment: I understand, but I don't see how can I apply this actually :/

Comment: [Here](http://blog.stata.com/2011/08/22/use-poisson-rather-than-regress-tell-a-friend/) is one brief explanation, with many references, also in the comments, to check out if you want to know more.